# Recursive query with sum in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I must store a lot of projects in my DB. Each project can have child projects. The structure looks like a tree:

```
                                     Project
                            /           |             \
                    ProjectChild1    ProjectChild2    [...]    ProjectChild[n]
                    /       |
 ProjectChildOfChild1    ProjectChildOfChild2
```

The level of the tree is unknow.
I'm thinking to create a table like this:

Table `Projects`:

```
project_ID id_unique PRIMARY_KEY
project_NAME text
project_VALUE numeric
project_PARENT id_unique
```

In this case, the column `project_PARENT` will store the id of the parent project, if exists.

For my application I need to retrieve the total value of a project, for this I need to sum the values of every project child and the root project.

I know that I need to use recursivity, but I don't know how to do this in Postgres.

Comment: See the recursive section in the [WITH clause docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html)

Comment: `id_unique` being a custom type or domain I assume ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a simplified version of [@a_horse's *correct* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26660411/939860) (after discussion with OP in comments).
Works with *any* (reasonably finite) number of levels in the recursion.

#### Total price for given `project_id`

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT project_id AS project_parent, project_value
   FROM   projects
   WHERE  project_id = 1 -- enter id of the base project here !

   UNION  ALL 
   SELECT p.project_id, p.project_value
   FROM   cte
   JOIN   projects p USING (project_parent)
)
SELECT sum(project_value) AS total_value
FROM   cte;
```

#### Total price for all projects

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT project_id, project_id AS project_parent, project_value
   FROM   projects
   WHERE  project_parent IS NULL  -- all base projects

   UNION  ALL 
   SELECT c.project_id, p.project_id, p.project_value
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   projects p USING (project_parent)
   )
SELECT project_id, sum(project_value) AS total_value
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=42ced0af869cac24c34211af54f8ad17)* (with correct test case)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f48ad/203)</sub>

Comment: Worked! I still confuse how this works, but the query is perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GuilhermeBatista: All's well that ends well. :)

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
with recursive project_tree as (
   select project_id, 
          project_name,
          project_value,
          project_parent
   from projects
   where project_id = 42 -- << the id of the "base" project
   union all 
   select p.project_id,
          p.project_name,
          p.project_value,
          p.project_parent
   from projects p
     join project_tree t on t.project_id = p.project_parent
)
select sum(project_value)
from project_tree;
```

The first part of the union needs to select the project that you want to evaluate (the "child" project). The recursive join will the walk up the tree and retrieve all parent projects.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name thank you for the answer, I'll try and give the feedback asap.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. If in "project_id" I put the ID of the root project, the query returns only the value of the root project.
If I put the ID of the low level project (a project form the leaf of the tree) the query returns the sum of the parents projects and the project itself, but don't include the "siblings" projects.

Comment: @GuilhermeBatista: sorry I don't get you. Please edit your question and add some sample data and the expected output. Ideally create the sample data as a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: the site sqlfiddle.com is offline, so I'll try to explain using images.
The first one is a query showing all my register in the table:
http://i.imgur.com/0TuAnfH.png

I changed the name "value" to "goal".

So when I put the ID of the first project (the base project) I get the following result:
http://i.imgur.com/h2J70ud.png

The sum is only the first project goal, not the sum of all goals of the tree.

Comment: @GuilhermeBatista: I reversed a typo in the join condition to fix it: `join project_tree t on t.project_id = p.project_parent`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks a lot, but didn't work either.

Comment: @GuilhermeBatista: It ***should*** work according to your description. The typo in `projetct_PARENT` isn't the problem, right? A project that has no parent has `project_PARENT IS NULL`? Consider this fiddle: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/58419/2**. I added a simplified version.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks one more time for you attention. I really appreciate. The query works fine with two levels of recusivity, but when we have three or more, levels, the query doesn't work. I used a modified version of your query to test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6ac8d/3

Comment: @GuilhermeBatista: Your update to the test data corrupted the test case due to serial numbers being moved out of place. I added another answer with a correct test case (with constant `project_id` to avoid the mistake).