# Calculate total price with 'WITH RECURSIVE'

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a table 'Leistung' (which means activity in english) and one for the match between two activitys with a given amount (benoetigt). So for example the activity with the ID 2 needs three activitys with the ID 3.

Each activity (leistung) has a price.

I now wanna calculate the total price for all activitys (leistung) including the price from the child activitys in the right amount.

Here are my tables with some testdata:

```
CREATE TABLE Leistung (
  lnr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  bezeichnung VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  price NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE benoetigt (
  lnr INTEGER REFERENCES Leistung(lnr),
  benoetigt_lnr INTEGER REFERENCES Leistung(lnr),
  amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (lnr,benoetigt_lnr)
);

INSERT INTO Leistung(lnr, bezeichnung, price) VALUES
  (1, 'Discokugel', 100),
  (2, 'Strobolicht', 100),
  (3, 'Verstärker', 90),
  (4, 'Gelaender',50),
  (5, 'Bühne',50),
  (6, 'Bühnenelement',20),
  (7, 'Stromverteiler', 40),
  (8, 'Stromkabel', 20);

INSERT INTO benoetigt (lnr, benoetigt_lnr, amount) VALUES
  (5,6,12),
  (1,7,1),
  (2,7,1),
  (7,8,1);
```

I am pretty shure that the solution only works with a 'WITH RECURSIV' query.
My first attempt ist this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE benoetigtlist(lnr,benoetigt_lnr,menge) AS (
  SELECT lnr, benoetigt_lnr, menge FROM benoetigt
    UNION ALL
  SELECT  b.lnr, b.benoetigt_lnr, b.menge
  FROM benoetigtlist bl, benoetigt b
  WHERE b.lnr = bl.benoetigt_lnr
)
SELECT * FROM benoetigtlist;
```

But i don't know how i can make the link between this result with the pricing from the activitys.

Or is this the wrong attempt?

Here is a SQL Fiddle from the testdata for better understanding: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/af50d)

EDIT: The desired output is a list with all activitys with the total price, including the price of their children.

For the testdata above the result should look like:

```
id  text          price
1  'Discokugel'     160  // 100 + 1*40 + 1*20
2  'Strobolicht'    160  // 100 + 1*40 + 1*20
3  'Verstärker'      90
4  'Gelaender'       50
5  'Bühne'          290  // 50 + 12*20  
6  'Bühnenelement'   20
7  'Stromverteiler'  60  // 40 + 1*20
8  'Stromkabel'      20
```

For example the activity with the ID 5 'Bühne' has a total price of 290, because the activity intself costs 50. Also this activity needs twelf activitys of ID 6 (which costs 20) (according to the first entry in 'benoetigt').

In summary: 50 + 12*20 = 290

In the as duplicate marked question the recursion only happens in one table. But i have the problem that the price information is in another table.

Comment: What is the desired output for that data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive query with sum in Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660189/recursive-query-with-sum-in-postgres)

Comment: Updated the question with desired output and why its not a duplicate. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you need to join result of your recursive CTE with your activity table twice (one join to get parent's price, another join to get price of child activity) and group by parent activity, summarizing cost of child activities:

```
WITH RECURSIVE benoetigtlist(lnr,benoetigt_lnr,menge) AS (
  SELECT lnr, benoetigt_lnr, amount 
  FROM benoetigt
    UNION ALL
  SELECT  bl.lnr, b.benoetigt_lnr, b.amount
  FROM benoetigtlist bl
  , benoetigt b
  WHERE b.lnr = bl.benoetigt_lnr
)
SELECT parent.lnr
  , parent.bezeichnung
  -- replace null with 0 if there are no child activities
  , parent.price + COALESCE(children_cost.cost, 0) AS cost
FROM Leistung parent
-- subquery that summarizes total cost of all children:
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT bl.lnr, SUM(bl.menge * l.price) as cost
  FROM benoetigtlist bl
  INNER JOIN Leistung l on bl.benoetigt_lnr = l.lnr
  GROUP BY bl.lnr
) children_cost ON children_cost.lnr = parent.lnr
ORDER BY parent.lnr
```